# What kind of data structure uses this format?

Tags: database, data-structures

I've been put on a project that saves all the data sent by a user as a blob in an SQL table, but they modify the data sent by us before storing it in the table.

A request like `www.somewebsite.com/request?id=3&color=ffffff`

gets stored as `a:3:{s:7:"request";s:0:"";s:2:"id";s:3:"290";s:5:"color";s:6:"ffffff";}`

So why are they storing everything with some kind of header that tells the length of the data? What is the name for this type of structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a format used by PHP serialize function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

This can be deserialized using unserialize function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Ah, yes.  Thank you.  I like the very first comment on the serialization page: `"Please! please! please! DO NOT serialize data and place it into your database."`

Comment: @n_b OTOH, if you're using an RDBMS and need to store ad-hoc, unqueryable-but-persistent data, it can make perfect sense.